# Get live market quotes on global indices

Tags: real-time, live, stocks

I need to connect to some sort of web service and get **live** data regarding global indices ( the DOW index, the S&P/TSX in Canada, the Hang Seng index in Hong Kong and so on ).  I need to display this data on my website.

I was wondering whether any of you know any organization that provides such stock/market/index information. I do not mind paying a monthly fee for such information.

Regards,
HideYourLoveWay

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Google Finance or Yahoo Finance? I'm not sure if the quotes are real time, but it may be a good place to start looking.

Comment: no google finance is not good ..it only has info for NYSE , NASDAQ, TSX as far as i understand ...it does not have info about brazil's stock exchange for example ... i need info about as many countries as possible...

Comment: ok ..yahoo finance has most of the indexes I'm interested in.... now the question becomes is it legal to get the data from yahoo and put it on my website ?

Comment: it turns out that it's not legal to get the data. from yahoo and redistribute it via my website.